# java: how to implement replaceAll method of StringBuilder

Tags: java

I implemented the replaceAll() method with matcher, which replaces all punctuations with "". But it always throws an exception: "**java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 6**"

```
private static StringBuilder filterPunctuation(StringBuilder sb){
    Pattern pattern =  Pattern.compile("(\\.)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sb);
    while(matcher.find()){
        sb.replace(matcher.start(), matcher.end(), "");  
// if sb.replace(matcher.start(),matcher.end()," "), it wil be right, but I want replace all punction with ""
    }
    return sb;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(filterPunctuation(new StringBuilder("test.,.")));
}
```

Comment: Why don't you show your implementation here?

Comment: Why would you do that? Why not just use the API that's there? Or is this "homework", in which case add that tag please

Comment: @Bohemian: There is no replaceAll for StringBuilder (of course, one does not lose much by going via String, I guess).

Comment: because I want to filter some punctuations, I guess it's will cost too many memories with string.replaceall()

Comment: @remy: I would assume string.replaceAll to be implemented reasonably efficiently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are going to change the StringBuilder (especially its length by removing characters) inside of the loop, you are going to need to get a new Matcher (because the old one will continue to look at the original buffer or an inconsistent mix of both).

[Take a look at how Jon Skeet would do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3472705/14955).

Comment: that's help me. now I know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I would assume this to do the trick

```
private static void filterPunctuation(StringBuilder sb)
{
    int l=sb.length();
    for (int i=0; i<l; i++) if (sb.charAt(i)=='.') sb.deleteCharAt(l--);
}
```

No need to return it as you are working on the same reference.

Comment: +1 I like simple. You should probably modify your code to show how it would handle commas, brackets etc

Comment: That might become one ugly || chain ;) remy's original code doesnt take them into account so far, hence I omitted them