# How to replace a single char at an index by a string?

Tags: java, string

I have a String "speed,7,red,fast". I want to replace the 7 by a String "Seven". How do I do that ?

**More details -**

7 can be replaced by ANY string and not just "Seven". It could also be "SevenIsHeaven".
I don't want to replace all occurrences of 7. Only 7 at the specified index, ie use the index of 7 to replace 7 by some string.

Comment: I feel like you have two questions here. a) What's the best way to convert a `numeric` value to its `alpha` equal? b) How to replace these values?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/manipstrings.html

Comment: Did you look for "replace string Java" in google? You'll be amazed from the results..

Comment: When you say, specified index, do you mean the character index or the index of the string in what looks to be a comma-separated list of strings?

Comment: @MarounMaroun, a replace is not sufficient for his question

Comment: @chrisw69 After his edit you're right.

Comment: @vikingsteve - use the index of 7 to replace 7 by some string. The index must be involved in your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 replaceAll("7", "Seven") //simple as that
```

**EDIT**

Then *you should look for the specified index*.

```
 String input = "test 7 speed,7,red,fast yup 7 tr";
    int indexInteresdIn = 13;
    if(input.charAt(indexInteresdIn) == '7'){
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(input);
        builder.replace(indexInteresdIn, indexInteresdIn+1, "Seven");
        System.out.println(builder.toString());
    }
```

Comment: My first guess too, though I think OP wants to able to replace all `numeric`s?

Comment: OP says he only wants to replace the specified occurence of 7, not all.

Comment: Ok, so we're just talking about a simple replace of a specified value to another specified value? In that case +1 for this answer.

Comment: @vikingsteve this is part of the update, it was not originally in the question ;)

Answer (score 4):

Because `String` is immutable you should use `StringBuilder` for better performance.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

```
yourStringBuiler.replace(
                   yourStringBuiler.indexOf(oldString),
                   yourStringBuiler.indexOf(oldString) + oldString.length(),
                   newString);`
```

If you want to replace a whole `String` like the `String.replaceAll()` does you could create an own function like this:

```
public static void replaceAll(StringBuilder builder, String from, String to)
{
    int index = builder.indexOf(from);
    while (index != -1)
    {
        builder.replace(index, index + from.length(), to);
        index += to.length(); // Move to the end of the replacement
        index = builder.indexOf(from, index);
    }
}
```

Source:
[Replace all occurrences of a String using StringBuilder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472663/replace-all-occurences-of-a-string-using-stringbuilder)

However if you doesn't need it frequently and performance is not that important a simple `String.replaceAll()` will do the trick, too.

Comment: That only replaces a character for a character. What if he wants to replace a character with a longer string?

Answer (score 2):

How about simply like below ?

```
 String str =  "speed,7,red,fast";
str = str.replace("7", "Seven");
```

> 7 can be replaced by ANY string and not just "Seven". It could also be
>   "SevenIsHeaven". I don't want to replace all occurrences of 7. Only 7
>   at the specified index.

Or if you wanna use regex to replace the first numeric to a meaningful String.

```
 String str =  "speed,7,red,fast";
str = str.replaceFirst("\\d", "Seven");
```

Comment: that replaces all occurences. maybe replaceFirst() instead of replace() ?

Answer (score 0):

better way is to store the string itself in an array, spiting it at a space.

```
String s[];
static int index; 
s = in.readLine().spilt(" ");
```

Now scan the array for the specified word, at the specified index and replace that with the String you desire.

```
for(int i =0;i<s.length; i++)
{
 if((s[i] == "7")&&(i==index))
{
  s[i]= "Seven";
}
}
```