# Replace character in StringBuilder

Tags: java

I have a StringBuilder and want to use replace method for a character.
code given below

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("01-02-2013");
```

How can i replace '-' with '/'   ?

Comment: You could simply use [`toString().replace("-", "/")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472663/replace-all-occurences-of-a-string-using-stringbuilder

Comment: check this method http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#setCharAt(int, char)

Comment: -1 The answer is practically in the question, it is hard to imagine you put any thought in to it or did any research or tried anything.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If don't want to convert the `StringBuilder` to a `String` or you need to keep using it/preserve it, then you could do something like this...

```
for (int index = 0; index < sb.length(); index++) {
    if (sb.charAt(index) == '-') {
        sb.setCharAt(index, '/');
    }
}
```

If you don't care then you could do something like...

```
String value = sb.toString().replace("-", "/");
```

Comment: Please be aware of replace(CharSequence, CharSequence) vs String.replace(char, char), the 2nd form is faster of course as it is a straight forward replacement rather than a Pattern replacement - If you look at the source code of each form you will see what I'm talking about.

Comment: @Guido Medina It is not just a replacement. It rewrites all the string to a new array. May be to sustain "immutability". I hoped StringBuilder does it straightforward but looks things are even worse with it. "Convert to String for that" sounds confusing with " A string buffer is like a String, but can be modified." or "use StringBuilder.append instead of String.+ for perfomance".

Answer (score 7):

Try this way

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("01-02-2013");

            sb.replace(sb.indexOf("-"), sb.indexOf("-")+1, "/") ;
            sb.replace(sb.indexOf("-"), sb.indexOf("-")+1, "/") ;
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Better approch is

```
sb.toString().replaceAll("-", "/");
```

Comment: indexes are is hard coded

Comment: Doesn't `replaceAll` take `regex`? I think it should be `replace` method.

Answer (score 1):

You should have searched a little bit about this.

Anyways, when starting to program in java, the best way to know what you can do with java in-built objects is to go to the javadoc of that class and there you will get to know plenty of thing.

In your case, you'll find your answer here : [StringBuilder javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#replace%28int,%20int,%20java.lang.String%29)

Use `replace` method.

Comment: 1) it has completely different parameters 
2) not just replaces the char value, but capable of changing length, so rebuilding buffer
3)Even if used indirectly via indexOf, IndexOf also takes only String. 
So

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the characters directly to the string itself.

```
sb.append(("blah-blah").replace('-', '_'));
```

Would output

```
blah_blah
```

Comment: There is no replace(char, char) function for StringBuilder

Comment: I already tested this, it works fine. sb = StringBuilder, not StringBuffer.

Comment: @sanbhat Yeah, I thought that to, but Rogue is replaing the characters BEFORE they append to the `StringBuilder` ... `("blah-blah").replace('-', '_')` - A little tricky...

Comment: Very true. If you wanted to append post-appending (i.e. the whole string), then your own method of sb.toString().replace('-', '/'); would be more ideal. Though, case by case it's all flexibility.