# Guessing symbols in a Sting word java

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

Got a String like:

```
String str = "###############";
```

Got guess word, for example:

```
String guess = "Java"
```

User must guess word:

```
User input:

Sava
```

Sring should be:

```
String str = "#a#a###########";
```

all right symbols placed on their indexes

`String` is immutable class.

I chose `Stringbuilder`

```
 for (int i = 0; i < length ; i++) {
    if (rnd.charAt(i) == guess.charAt(i) && rnd.charAt(i) != '#'){
       sb.append(rnd.charAt(i));
        }
   }

 System.out.println(sb);

 sb.delete(0, sb.length());
```

`Stringbuilder` add right symbols not on possition `'i'`, but on the last indexes.

Example:

```
guess word: Java

user input Sala:

System.out.println(sb);

###############aa
```

How I can achieve needed result?
And what tools should I use?

needed result:

```
Example:
guess word Java:

user input Sala:


System.out.println(sb);
#a#a###########
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace character in StringBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579273/replace-character-in-stringbuilder)

Comment: Please read: [How to create a Minimal, **Reproducible** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work like this:

```
private static String word(){
    String guess = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
    return guess;
}

private static void guessWord(String[]arr) {
    int random = new Random().nextInt(arr.length);
    String rnd = arr[random];

    int length = 15;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String guess = "";

    int rndLength = length - rnd.length();
    int guessLength = length - guess.length();


    do {
        System.out.println("Enter a word: ");
        guess = word();

       if (sb.length() < length){
           for (int i = 0; i < length ; i++) {
               sb.append("#");
           }
       }

        for (int i = 0; i < length  && i < rnd.length() && i < guess.length();  i++) {
            if (rnd.charAt(i) == guess.charAt(i)){
                sb.setCharAt(i, rnd.charAt(i));
                sb.delete(length, sb.length());
            }
        }

        if (rnd.equals(guess)){
            System.out.println("Guess word: " + rnd);
            break;
        }else if (!rnd.equals(guess)) {
            System.out.println(sb);
        }
    }while (!rnd.equals(guess));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "#a#a###########";
        String guess = "Java";
        String input = "Sala";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < str.length() && i < guess.length() && i < input.length(); i++) {
            // In case of a match, append the matched character
            if (guess.charAt(i) == input.charAt(i)) {
                sb.append(guess.charAt(i));
            } else {// Else append the placeholder symbol from `str`
                sb.append(str.charAt(i));
            }
        }

        // Append the remaining placeholder characters from `str`
        sb.append(str.substring(i));

        // Display
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
#a#a###########
```