# Why doesn't replaceAll work in this line of code?

Tags: java, string

```
    String weatherLocation = weatherLoc[1].toString();
weatherLocation.replaceAll("how","");
weatherLocation.replaceAll("weather", "");
weatherLocation.replaceAll("like", "");
weatherLocation.replaceAll("in", "");
weatherLocation.replaceAll("at", "");
weatherLocation.replaceAll("around", "");
test.setText(weatherLocation);
```

weatherLocation still contains "like in"

Answer (score 12):

Strings are immutable. [`String#replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method will create a new string. You need to re-assign the result back to the variable:

```
weatherLocation = weatherLocation.replaceAll("how","");
```

Now, since the `replaceAll` method returns the modified string, you can also chain multiple `replaceAll` call in single line. In fact, you don't need a `replaceAll()` here. It is required, when you want to replace substring matching a regex pattern. Simply use [`String#replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) method:

```
weatherLocation = weatherLocation.replace("how","")
                                 .replace("weather", "")
                                 .replace("like", "");
```

Comment: Also, quite wrong :)

Comment: i failed completely with my answer, yes -.- removed it.

Answer (score 6):

As Rohit Jain said, Strings are immutable; in your case you could chain calls to `replaceAll` to avoid multiple affectations.

```
String weatherLocation = weatherLoc[1].toString()
        .replaceAll("how","")
        .replaceAll("weather", "")
        .replaceAll("like", "")
        .replaceAll("in", "")
        .replaceAll("at", "")
        .replaceAll("around", "");
test.setText(weatherLocation);
```

Answer (score 2):

Exactly as Rohit Jain said, and also, since replaceAll takes regex, instead of chaining calls you can simply do something like

```
test.setText(weatherLocation.replaceAll("how|weather|like|in|at|around", ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that better will be to use `StringBuilder`/`StringBuffer` if you need to replace a lot of strings in text. Why? As Rohit Jain wrote `String` is immutable so every call of `replaceAll` method needs to create new object. Unlike `String`, `StringBuffer`/`StringBuilder` are mutable so it won't create new object (it will work on the same object).

You can read about StringBuilder for example in this Oracle tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html.

Comment: The problem is that `StringBuffer`/`StringBuilder` don't have a `replaceAll` method.

Comment: Of course, you are right but it doesn't mean that you can't replace strings in StringBuffer/StringBuilder. You can use `replace` method.

Comment: You can use http://stackoverflow.com/a/3472705/393487