# How to replace space with hyphen?

Tags: java, replace, stringbuffer

I want to replace Space with "-" what is the way

Suppose my code is

```
StringBuffer tokenstr=new StringBuffer();
tokenstr.append("technician education systems of the Cabinet has approved the following");
```

I want output

```
"technician-education-systems-of-the-Cabinet-has-approved-the-following"
```

thanks

Comment: you could use `String.replaceAll()`

Comment: @user2573153 i am using Stringbuffer not string.

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: `StringBuffer.toString().replaceAll(...)`?

Comment: @RC i didn't get you?

Comment: Is replacing spaces to `-` before they are added to Buffer option?

Comment: Why downvoting anything wrong in my question :(

Comment: Possible reason for downvote is that you haven't shown what have you tried to solve this problem. It creates impression of "plz send teh codez" type of question. Place your mouse over downvote button and you will see possible reasons for downvoting.

Comment: What was the need for a StringBuffer ? Seriously.. huh

Answer (score 4):

Like this,

```
StringBuffer tokenstr = new StringBuffer();
tokenstr.append("technician education systems of the Cabinet has approved the following");
System.out.println(tokenstr.toString().replaceAll(" ", "-"));
```

and like this as well

```
System.out.println(tokenstr.toString().replaceAll("\\s+", "-"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the StringBuffer object then you need to iterate it and replace the character:

```
 for (int index = 0; index < tokenstr.length(); index++) {
            if (tokenstr.charAt(index) == ' ') {
                tokenstr.setCharAt(index, '-');
            }
        }
```

or convert it into String then replace as below :

```
String value = tokenstr.toString().replaceAll(" ", "-");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
 StringBuffer tokenstr=new StringBuffer();
 tokenstr.append("technician education systems of the Cabinet has approved the following".replace(" ", "-"));
 System.out.print(tokenstr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this :

```
//First store your value in string object and replace space with "-" before appending it to StringBuffer. 
String str = "technician education systems of the Cabinet has approved the following";
str = str.replaceAll(" ", "-");
StringBuffer tokenstr=new StringBuffer();
tokenstr.append(str);
System.out.println(tokenstr);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to write custom `replaceAll` method. Where you need to find out src string index and replace those string sub-string with destination string.

Please find a code snippet by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472663/replace-all-occurences-of-a-string-using-stringbuilder)

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to jump back and forth between StringBuffer and String classes, you can do this:

```
StringBuffer tokenstr = new StringBuffer();
tokenstr.append("technician education systems of the Cabinet has approved the following");

int idx=0;
while( idx = tokenstr.indexOf(" ", idx) >= 0 ) {
    tokenstr.replace(idx,idx+1,"-");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

/*You can use below method pass your String parameter and get result as       String  spaces replaced with hyphen*            /

```
 private static String replaceSpaceWithHypn(String str) {
    if (str != null && str.trim().length() > 0) {
        str = str.toLowerCase();
        String patternStr = "\\s+";
        String replaceStr = "-";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        str = matcher.replaceAll(replaceStr);
        patternStr = "\\s";
        replaceStr = "-";
        pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
        matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        str = matcher.replaceAll(replaceStr);
    }
    return str;
}
```