# How can I manipulate part of a string in java using regular expressions

Tags: java, regex

I have a string that looks like this:

```
String pathTokenString = "CMS/{brandPath}/Shows/{showPath}";
```

I want to remove the Shows part and everything that follows. I also want to replace "{brandPath}" with a token that I'm given.

This has been my approach. However, my string isn't getting updated at all:

```
//remove the '/Shows/{showPath}'
pathTokenString = pathTokenString.replace("/Shows$", "");

//replace passed in brandPath in the tokenString
String answer = pathTokenString.replace("{(.*?)}", brandPath);
```

Is there something wrong with my regular expressions?

Comment: `/Shows$`===>`/Shows.*$`

Comment: @vks I just tried that and it didn't work. Is it a problem with using replace()? should I be using something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method instead of `replace` when you want to pass a regex string as the pattern to be replaced.  Also your regex patterns should be updated:

```
pathTokenString = pathTokenString.replaceAll("/Shows.*$", "");

// The curly braces need to be escaped because they denote quantifiers
String answer = pathTokenString.replaceAll("\\{(.*?)\\}", brandPath);
```

Comment: this worked great. However, I had a quick follow-up. I now want to use a StringBuilder since I know it's not efficient to create all these strings. Is there an equivalent of replaceAll() for a StringBuilder? thanks!

Comment: @DanielD If it's just for these strings I don't really see how a `StringBuilder` could be more efficient. Your code is also more concise. Yet you can see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472663/replace-all-occurences-of-a-string-using-stringbuilder.