# String .replace() not applicable

Tags: java, nxt, lejos-nxj

I am trying to remove the non-number characters from my string.

I have tried using the `.replace()` method but this returns with the error:

> The method replace(char, char) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)

Code:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
File f = new File("coords.txt");
if (f.exists()) {
    FileInputStream in;
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(f);
        p.load(in);
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Failed to load coordinates");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        Button.waitForAnyPress();
        System.exit(0);
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("No coordinates found");
    while (!Button.ESCAPE.isPressed()) {
        Thread.yield();
    }
    System.exit(0);
}
```

When I print out the string `gg`, initialized like:

```
String gg = p.toString();
```

I get the output: `Object020f458`.

My computer highlights the error on the replace:

```
gg = gg.replace("{", "");
gg = gg.replace("=", "");
gg = gg.replace("}", "");

int commaLoc = gg.indexOf(",");
int x = Integer.parseInt(gg.substring(0,commaLoc));
int y = Integer.parseInt(gg.substring(commaLoc + 1));
```

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? `String.replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)` was introduced in Java 1.5.

Comment: @JonSkeet my JDK is 1.7

Comment: You should probably define what "my computer" means. Are you compiling via command line or using an IDE?

Comment: @LppEdd Im using a NXT which is external, using the Lejos library on eclipse

Comment: @TotallyNotSuspisousAccount see my answer. Hope I got the APIs from the right place.

Comment: show us, how `coords.txt` looks like, please.

Comment: the problem is not `replace` (yet), it is how you access `Properties`! `Properties.toString() -> "Object020f458"` looks ok! Properties are rather accessed in the way: `Properties.get("myKey")` (to get 1 property ... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html)

Comment: @xerx593 currently coords.txt has  50,70  and nothing else in it

Comment: that doesn't sound like ["Properties"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the String I was using was actually using was a property I had to retrieve it like a property which will format it itself

```
 int Count = Integer.parseInt(p.getProperty("Number_of_properties"));
   for(int i = 1; i < Count; i++)
   {
    int x = Integer.parseInt(p.getProperty("x"+i));
    int y = Integer.parseInt(p.getProperty("y"+i));

   }
```

I also had to change my text file to match the property format:

```
Number_of_properties = 4
x1 = 150
y1 = 70
x2 = 55
y2 = 77
```

Answer (score 2):

So I was having a look at NXT and its APIs ([JavaDocs](http://www.lejos.org/nxt/nxj/api/))
Btw, I am by no mean an expert on NXT and leJOS, I'm guessing.

You can see by the JavaDoc, that the `replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)` method is not present.

[image]

While I wouldn't solve the problem in such a way, you can try using a `StringBuilder` to remove the unwanted chars.

See for example a Jon Skeet answer for ideas
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3472705/1392277

You can extract a method such as:

```
private String removeChars(
        final String originalString,
        final String charsToRemove) {
    final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(originalString);
    int i = stringBuilder.indexOf(charsToRemove);

    while (i != -1) {
        stringBuilder.replace(i, i + charsToRemove.length(), "");
        i = stringBuilder.indexOf(charsToRemove, i);
    }

    return stringBuilder.toString();        
}
```

Comment: I input your code and it brought up the error: The method replace(int, int, String) is undefined for the type StringBuilder

Comment: @TotallyNotSuspisousAccount than you have to find another solution. See xerx593 answer

Answer (score 1):

problem:

```
gg = gg.replace("{", "");
gg = gg.replace("=", "");
gg = gg.replace("}", "");
```

error message:

> The method replace(char, char) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)

Please try to replace with `Character.MIN_VALUE`:

Replace `"` with `'`, then replace all `''` (, since java "doesn't like the empty character literal") with `Character.MIN_VALUE`):

```
gg = gg.replace('{', Character.MIN_VALUE);
gg = gg.replace('=', Character.MIN_VALUE);
gg = gg.replace('}', Character.MIN_VALUE);
```

Character.MIN_VALUE is *not* empty character, but *closest to it* :), and converts (with a `String.replcae(char,char)` test):

```
{foo=bar}
```

to:

```
\u0000foo\u0000bar\u0000
```

...which appears hard to copy&paste, but "looks like blanks" :)

Comment: ...but this is not your actual problem.

Comment: I think a StringBuilder solution is better suited. MIN_VALUE is not really removing the char, as you said

Comment: ...sure! this is a *total hack* approach :) ....but still confusing, why `String.replace("{", "")` not works.

Comment: See my answer above. Most probably he is using a "proprietary/custom" JDK API.

Comment: ahmmhk, i got "api" and "lego", but i didnt realize it's a "a custom jdk". You are right, better solution: StringBuilder/JohnSkeet always good! :)

Comment: I'm not really sure on the custom JDK, but I mean, it's on Lego and probably they've put some restriction on the amount of usable APIs. Felt strange reading Jon Skeet comment on this question :)

Comment: but i leave this post, because (i found nothing) no one tried/ posted yet: `String.replace(char, Character.MIN_VALUE)` :)

Comment: thx, bro! :) ..at least [StringBuilder](http://www.lejos.org/nxt/nxj/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) *is in* that jdk! pheew! ..but still I think OP has to solve the "`Properties` problem", too.

Comment: As many SO questions, this one has business-logic + technical problems. I think that if the OP takes a board and begins drawing a diagram/flow-chart of the domain problem, this thing won't even be required.

Comment: Found, VM name is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TinyVM
See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LeJOS#NXJ_and_the_Java_platform

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)
```

This will replace all matching expressions with the replacements.

```
gg = gg.replaceAll("{", ""); // replace all "{" with "".
gg = gg.replaceAll("=", "");
gg = gg.replaceAll("}", "");
```

Comment: That will throw an exception in normal Java, because `replaceAll` accepts a regular expression pattern. You'd need `"\\{` instead of "{". And it looks like `replaceAll` isn't available in this environment either.

Answer (score -1):

The error must have been highlighted on below two line and not for replace function

```
   int x = Integer.parseInt(gg.substring(0,commaLoc));
   int y = Integer.parseInt(gg.substring(commaLoc + 1));
```

you forgot to put comma in second line. It should be

```
   int y = Integer.parseInt(gg.substring(commaLoc, + 1));
```

Still it wont work because you are trying substring function with invalid range (as value of commaLoc is -1).

Try replacing those last two lines as below just to make it error free.

```
      int x = Integer.parseInt(gg.substring(6, 7));
      int y = Integer.parseInt(gg.substring(7, 8));
```

Comment: Thanks for advice. What I did is debug the entire code on Java 1.8, however I found the issue in mentioned lines. And not replace function